# Javascript giving Event as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to Use the function

```
$.("#SomeId").submit(function(e){});
```

but more like this

```
function changePassword(e, url){}
```

I want to make a Ajax request but I cant use

```
e.preventDefault()
```

At this point I got this code. It is not working, the form still makes a get request

```
function changePassword(url){
    const data = $(this).serializeArray();
    this.submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success(response){
                switch(response){
                    case 'doesntMatch':
                        Materialize.toast(`Die Passwörter stimmen nicht überein.`, 3000, "red");
                        break;
                    case 'success':
                        Materialize.toast(`Die Änderung des Passwortes war erfolgreich!`, 3000, "green");
                        break;
                    case 'logout':
                        window.location.href = "/logout";
                        break;
                    case 'toShort':
                        Materialize.toast(`Das angegebene Passwort ist zu kurz. Es muss mindestens acht Zeichen lang sein`, 3000, "red");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Materialize.toast(`Serverfehler`, 3000, "red");
                        break;
                }
            },
            error(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });


}
```

My html part is this

```
    <form id="changePw" onsubmit="return changePassword('/admin/changepw')">
```

What could I possibly change?

Comment: Remove the `this.submit` part of that code. Also why would you need to pass the url in the function call? It's hard coded in the element so it's not going to change easily.

Comment: `changePassword` needs to return false if you want to stop the form from submitting.

Comment: I need the url, because i want to use this function for 2 different things. If i remove the submit part, or even with it, it makes a get request with the content of the form. 
And i dont want to return false, because I want to submit it via ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that function is being called on submit with the form's `onsubmit` attribute means that you don't need to set a form handler in javacript. (which would be done with `$(form).submit(myfunction)` btw, not `form.submit()`
, the form's [`submit` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) does not take any parameters).

You will need to pass the context (form) in as a second parameter since `this` will be out of context in the function when handing the submit with the onsumbit attribute.

Now, you just need to return false from the handler and it will prevent the form from submitting.

```
<form id="changePw" onsubmit="return changePassword('/admin/changepw', this)">
```

---

```
function changePassword(url, form) {
  const data = $(form).serializeArray();
  $.post({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success(response) {
      switch (response) {
        case 'doesntMatch':
          Materialize.toast(`Die Passwörter stimmen nicht überein.`, 3000, "red");
          break;
        case 'success':
          Materialize.toast(`Die Änderung des Passwortes war erfolgreich!`, 3000, "green");
          break;
        case 'logout':
          window.location.href = "/logout";
          break;
        case 'toShort':
          Materialize.toast(`Das angegebene Passwort ist zu kurz. Es muss mindestens acht Zeichen lang sein`, 3000, "red");
          break;
        default:
          Materialize.toast(`Serverfehler`, 3000, "red");
          break;
      }
    },
    error(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Okay that seems to work, but now the $.(this).serializeArray(); isnt working anymore. It says it is an array with length 0.

Comment: @LukasGermerott - missed that.. see the updated answer.